# SparkNLP Text classification using BertSentenceEmbeddings

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am struggling with implementing classification usecase using the `BertSentenceEmbeddings` in python. Mostly I get `classNotFoundError` and I think I am unable to figure out the right versions of libraries (spark-nlp, pyspark).
I followed most of options suggested on web but had no luck.

Any suggestions/tutorial would be the great help. Thanks.

Here's my [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gJ_yATbniiXnYyMd25fB9pIsjCK5wr1y?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp-workshop/blob/master/tutorials/Certification_Trainings/Public/5.Text_Classification_with_ClassifierDL.ipynb) helped me solve this error.

Thank you Maziyar for the help on Spark-NLP slack.